# xsd for a tag that allows string content by deafult and child tags in case the attribute is specified

Tags: xml, xsd, attributes

Can we define xsd that allows the following two xmls

1) If no attribute is specified , it should allow string content only

`<tagname>
String content
</tagname>`

2)If the attribute "encrypted=true" is defined it should have additional child tags

`<tagname encrypted="true">
<value> encrypted content </value>
<certificate> version string </certificate>
</tagname>`

Thank you !

Comment: XSD 1.0 cannot express your constraint but XSD 1.1 using CSA could; see duplicate link for an example.